# Sending and receiving encrypted data from a javascript app

Tags: javascript, encryption

I have an interactive html5 app that let's people customize products on the client-side. As a user is customizing, the price updates based on individual component prices.

Once this is done, the person hits checkout, I send the customization to the server, and the server takes over the checkout process.

Obviously sending price data to the server is pointless, since anyone could spoof the POST data. So, I tried writing a server side script that will regenerate the price according to the components selected (sent to the server with the customization data), and show that on checkout instead. However, the server side calculation is proving very difficult, due to complex customizations offered; and it seems like I have to rewrite the entire client-side customization logic on the server-side (which is a lot of work).

Before I continue writing the server-side script I wanted to know if it is at all possible to send the price data to the server in a way (asymmetric key auth perhaps) that cannot be spoofed?

Comment: Nope. The only code you can trust is code on your server.

Comment: Remove all your pricing logic from the client side and put it on the server.

Comment: It is a lot of work to duplicate, but it is work you need to do. NEVER take these kind of shortcuts, they will burn you badly when you least expect it. You should also use HTTPS in addition (not as an answer) if you are taking payments.

Comment: I think sending the price data from client to server is a bad idea. It's fine if you want to have some logic that updates the prices on the client side, but it should all be reproducable on the server side once you check out.

Comment: I am already using https, but as suggested that doesn't solve the problem. I guess I am stuck with rewriting stuff on the server. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Never trust the information clients send you.

To answer your question, it is possible to use encryption to send data from the client to the server. However, the problem here is the data being encrypted can be modified even before the encryption. So, encryption is not really the solution. The client might modify the data before encryption and the server will not know this if there are no server-side checking.

Even with public-private key encryption, this will still be unsafe. There will only be an assurance that your data will not be tampered from the user to the server. It cannot be spoofed by *third parties* but your user can spoof it, thereby making the encryption pointless. So, **do not trust the user** to send you valid legitimate information.

You should really double check everything in the server. And you will not need encryption unless privacy is an issue (which probably is based on your description). This can easily be solved by using https.

The client-side javascript you created can serve as immediate feedback to the users, they see prices as they make changes to the forms. This is **good** because they do not need to wait for the server to process the information, which the server should upon submission of the form.

Answer (score 2):

You should never never never trust client-side code.  If you want to spare yourself the headache of rewriting your client-side code, you *could* just put the relevant JavaScript on the server and call it from your server code (Not that I'm suggesting you should do that).  Another thing I would recommend doing is recalculating the price based on the contents of a full postback once the user is done with their customization, and then displaying the recalculated price to the user in order to allow them to confirm it.  That way if any client-side shenanigans have occurred, the user will get the real price anyway, and I'm sure that if it differs even slightly from the previous price, your support people will hear all about it.